# Disable Ribbon button in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

I'm trying to make it so that a custom button is disabled depending on the toggle state of another custom button on the Excel ribbon. I have a button defined in my ribbons' XML as follows:

```
<button id="ButtonCalc" label="Re-Calculate" size="large" onAction="calc" image="Calculate" getEnabled="disableRefresh"/>
```

The call-back for the getEnabled tag is:

```
'Callback for ButtonCalc getEnabled
Sub disableRefresh(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)

If calcState Then

    enabled = True

Else
    enabled = False

End If
End Sub
```

The term "calcstate" is a boolean operation controlled by the toggle button:

```
<toggleButton id="ButtonMode" label="Light Mode" size="large" onAction="ToggleCalcClicked" image="Mode" getPressed="checkLight"/>
```

VBA for this part:

```
Public calcState As Boolean

Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub ToggleCalcClicked(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)

calcState = Not calcState
Worksheets("Setup").Range("L47").Value = calcState

Call ChangeCalcState

End Sub
```

Everything works, except the button for Re-calculate is permanently disabled. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the `InvalidateControl` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/iribbonui-invalidatecontrol-method-office

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to invalidate the control to change the visibility or enabled properties.

```
Public calcState As Boolean

Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub ToggleCalcClicked(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)

  calcState = Not calcState
  Worksheets("Setup").Range("L47").Value = calcState

  ChangeCalcState
  MyRibbon.InvalidateControl("ButtonCalc")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I just found it. Callbacks for xml lines <command... etc. > have two arguments and must have the following syntax:

```
'Callback for HyperlinkInsert onAction
Sub Test(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef cancelDefault)
End Sub
```

With this syntax no more problem... and to think that I've been on it for more than two hours and my searches had yielded nothing